# Not able to play youtube video embedded in iframe created via JS

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, youtube-api

​Hello,
when I embed a youtube video into iframe that is not made via HTML  tag but created with JavaScript (document.createElement()) video can not be played and only error message “Video unavailable” is shown.

Additional info:

- First iframe does not have a src attribute.
- The document of iframe is created programmatically. Second
  (video-embedding) iframe is part of the first iframe document.
- This page is running on localhost.
- This behavior is happening also on online applications running on own domain.
- This behavior does not happen for all videos, i noticed it is happening mainly with music videos.
- All videos have embedding enabled so this is not reason why those videos cannot be played.

[gif showing behavior here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teRpq.gif)

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<div>
<iframe id="myFrame" style="width: 600px ; height: 350px" src="iframeVideo.html" frameborder="1"
allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
<div id="video"></div>

<script>
var container = document.getElementById("video");
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.style.width = "600px";
frame.style.height = "400px";

frame.onload = function () {
if (frame.contentDocument) {
var fdoc = frame.contentDocument;
var vframe = fdoc.createElement("iframe");

vframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/NEIwl93Yr8o";
vframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
vframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "");
vframe.style.width = "500px";
vframe.style.height = "281px";

fdoc.body.appendChild(vframe);
}
}
container.appendChild(frame);
</script>

</html>
```

**iframeVideo.html:**

```
<html>
<iframe id="myFrame" style="width: 500px ; height: 281px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NEIwl93Yr8o" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the console of the browser (F12) if there are errors or warnings.

Comment: there is only this warning:
_A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032_

Comment: check also the "network" tab and see the responses of the requests - pay close attention to the response of the iframe. it *might* be possible that you need add an additional parameter in your iframe; IIRC, the URL of the video i the iframe would be: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/NEIwl93Yr8o?origin=http:yourwebsite.com`.

Comment: I already tried to play with parameters that is youtube offering, also i was looking into requests and i haven't found any useful information that would indicate where problem lies or what could be solution. (maybe i misslooked something)

Comment: other option could be: post your question on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) - it might have some about the restriction of music videos or `document.createElement` = it is need you create the DOM elements in this way? - try with DOM/html controlls already on the page. Maybe it is a initialization of the internal variables for the iframe...

Comment: I sent already issue to tracker. And yes, creating this iframe dynamically is requirement.

Comment: Please [edit] your question by adding the issue tracker link in the "additional info".

Answer (score 2):

The video in your example code has been set to be non-embeddable by whoever uploaded it to YouTube. You can see this by viewing the video successfully on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEIwl93Yr8o) but not by going straight to https://www.youtube.com/embed/NEIwl93Yr8o (note the "play" button, when clicked, says "video unavailable").  You can compare that to, for example, https://www.youtube.com/embed/Np1zODg5cqc, an embedder-URL which you can successfully watch by clicking the play-button.

Some YouTube videos can't be embedded, and unless you have control over the appropriate YouTube account, there's nothing you can do about that (except ask the owner to make it embeddable).

Comment: I have tried it already before with own video I uploaded to youtube, where i enabled embedding and it is not working. So i do not think this is the reason why some videos does not work.

Comment: [Here you can see, this video has embedding enabled](https://imgur.com/a/zBUlvaK) (when you click to SHARE->EMBED under video)

Comment: @RadekM. please try going to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEIwl93Yr8o and right-clicking, copying the embed code, pasting it into the simplest web page you can, and trying to play it.  It doesn't play. It says "video unavailable" when you click "play".  Maybe it's different for you; I don't know where you are - maybe it's a geo thing.  I'm on the US west coast.

Comment: And video is working for me on simple static HTML page on localhost runned via xampp Apache @avocadatoria, I am in Europe